# Java Security Policy Preventing Access to Maven Resource Files

Tags: java, maven, security

I'm currently working on a Maven based project in Eclipse which I want to connect to a database using Hibernate + JPA. I have created a `persistence.xml` file and placed it in the directory `<project>/src/main/resources/META-INF`. When I run the application it will throw the very known exception `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named`

The contents of my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="NetworkMonDB">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>  
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

How I'm initializing this in my application:

```
public void initializeDatabase(){
    final HashMap<String, String> dbConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();

    dbConfig.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", this.properties.getProperty("database.uri"));
    dbConfig.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", this.properties.getProperty("database.usr"));
    dbConfig.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", this.properties.getProperty("database.psw"));
    final EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NetworkMonDB", dbConfig); //exception thrown at this point.
    this.entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
}
```

And here are my Maven Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I conducted some further tests (see edits for previous comments on identifying the problem) and it seems the problem comes from my currently used security policy. While I have a security policy file to use when the application is built and packaged in a jar file, I do not have one that will work inside the Eclipse IDE. As soon as I figure out what the best way to configure the security policy I will post it as an answer, unless someone else has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as described above was caused by a handling of the security policy and security manager. Since this application will eventually read from the hard drive, and work with RMI I need to use a security manager and security policy. However, when working inside the IDE you don't actually need to set a codebase value in the security policy file.

My current solution is to have this as my development area security policy:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

And then the security policy in use when I deploy my application would look like this:

```
grant codeBase "file:./MyApplication.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

I know that eventually I will need to provide a better more specific security policy for deployment that grants specific permissions to specific file locations and network values, but this should get me going until then.